# How many yuga cycles in one Brahma day

Tags: yuga, brahma, creation

According to this, there are 4.32 billion years in one Brahma day, i.e. age of the Universe.

Each Brahma day goes through yuga cycle of Satya, Treta, Dvapara, and Kali, which adds up to 4.32 billions years.

But according to several pictures of the 4 yugas, the total cycle adds up to 24,000 years, i.e. 11,500BC to 12,500AD is 24,000 years, is it not?

So I am really confused. Is this one Brahma day? Because I thought at the end of Kali yuga the Universe is destroyed and reborn.

Please explain this perspective according to Hindu beliefs.

[image]

And according to this [slide from YouTUBE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Qc4gz4bIdM), here are the durations, but I don't understand how it adds up to 24,000 human years ~~~ totally confused!

[image]

Comment: This is a duplicate of several other questions. Do a search of Hinduism SE.

Comment: These are exaggerated figures of year. Yes there are thousands of Yugas in a day of Brahma, but these Yugas are not consisting of so many years. In internet, many people have made them superlative for fun!